# In MAMP one .php file is working other gives a HTTP500 error

Tags: php, macos, mamp

I am using MAMP on macos  . Inside the .htdocs file ı put some php files to open in the browser . Although file names and path are correct login.php file is working well but on the other hand signup.php file gives me an error (http500 / localhost is currently unable to handle this request.). What could be the reason about that ? Any solution

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable display error for php by adding this code to at the beginning of your code (you can also enable error display globally in php.ini by setting `display_errors = on`).

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

after that you can trace the error.

Comment: I wrote this part inside php tags and outer of php tags but nothing is changed . Also tried adding echo before ini_set however  Only HTTP500 error is being showned to me.

Comment: @vees1 try to edit your php.ini or .htaccess. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/6934036